# How to find undefined or empty cells in a row with google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

so as the title says I would like to find the empty or undefined cells in a row while iterating row until my lastrow. But it says "TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined." Since it cant read undefined values and check it. You can see my code below. Thanks!

```
for (var row = startRow; row <= endRow; row++) {
    var rangeA = "A" + row;
    var rangeB = "H" + row;
    var range = rangeA + ":" + rangeB;
    var values = sheet1.getRange(range).getValues(); // get all data in one call

    for ( var ct = 0; ct <= 7; ct++) {
     if (values[ct][0]) = "")
       runloop = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Cause:

Arrays are indexed by rows first and then columns. For example, A1:H1 contains 1 row and 8 columns or 1 inner array and 8  elements in that 1 inner array`[[A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1,G1,H1]]`. Therefore, `values[1]` will be `undefined`( since there's only 1 inner array  whose index is 0).  The script is looping through inner array instead of looping through elements of the inner array.

#### Solution:

- Loop through the elements instead

#### Snippet:

```
if (values[0][ct] === "")
```

Comment: Its giving sytanx error for if (values[0][ct]) = "").

Comment: @Triath Syntax error was in your original post. I just copy/pasted. Anyway, Now fixed.

Comment: Not fixed still, there might be problem with values[0][ct].

Comment: @Triath update your question to show the latest modified script